# Sort by most viewed products

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, product-list

As we can see most viewed products in admin dashboard.

I want to use same attribute ( its from report ) to sort products on product catalog sort by dropdown (toolbar.phtml)

or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: may be this link will help you http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/273724/

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend [this extension](http://amasty.com/improved-sorting.html). It's not that expensive and it works great. I've used it for CE and EE both with success. Other than sorting by most viewed, you have other sorting options: Best sellers, biggest discounts (and others but these are the most useful).

---

<sub>I'm in no way associated with the extension provider. I just used the extension and liked it.</sub>

Comment: I second Marius' suggestion. I use it all of the time, and is a great way to improve listing results